# Setting range and breaks on scale on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(SITCD = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("GSO/TO", "IKOF", "JL", 
 "MES", "SSD", "USSD"), class = "factor"), Code = structure(c(27L, 
 21L, 3L, 25L, 26L, 20L, 2L, 28L, 230L, 16L, 4L, 10L, 15L, 1L), .Label = c("AAR-2107", 
 "AAR-643", "AAR-644", "AAR-995", "HAR-2956", "HAR-2957", "I-430", 
 "I-431", "I-432", "I-9490", "I-9491", "K-1461", "K-1740", "K-1915", 
 "K-2034", "K-2096", "K-2385", "K-2386", "K-2387", "K-3112", "K-3220", 
 "K-3224", "Lu-1095", "Lu-1103", "LU-3282", "LU-3283", "LU-3284", 
 "LU-3400", "Lu-487", "Lu-489,90", "Lu-491,92", "Lu-528", "Lu-529", 
 "Lu-530", "Lu-531", "Lu-585", "Lu-586", "Lu-608", "Lu-646", "Lu-647", 
 "Lu-648", "Lu-711", "Lu-714", "Lu-766", "Lu-768", "Lu-790", "Lu-792", 
 "Lu-793", "Lu-826", "Lu-827", "Lu-828", "Lu-829", "Lu-830", "Lu-831", 
 "Lu584", "M-1611", "M-1612", "M-1613", "M-1614", "M-1615", "M-1616", 
 "M-1617", "M-1618", "M-1619", "M-1620", "M-1621", "M-1622", "M-1623", 
 "M-1624", "OS-49305", "OS-49306", "OS-49308", "OS-49309", "OS-49311", 
 "OS-49312", "OS-49313", "OS-49314", "OS-49315", "OS-49384", "OS-49385", 
 "OS-49386", "OS-49387", "OS-49403", "OS-49414", "OS-49437", "OS-49440", 
 "OS-49441", "OS-49442", "OS-49493", "OS-49496", "OS-49499", "OS-49502", 
 "OS-49506", "OS-49515", "OS-49516", "OS-49517", "OS-49518", "OS-49519", 
 "OS-49520", "OS-49555", "OS-49558", "OS-49562", "OS-49565", "OS-49578", 
 "OS-49580", "OS-49581", "OS-49582", "OS-49583", "OS-49584", "OS-49605", 
 "OS-49606", "OS-49607", "OS-51568", "OS-51716", "OS-51759", "OS-51760", 
 "OS-51765", "OS-51766", "OS-51767", "OS-51769", "OS-51770", "OS-51774", 
 "OS-51775", "OS-51776", "OS-51845", "OS-51846", "OS-51847", "OS-51874", 
 "OS-51875", "OS-51882", "OS-51883", "OS-51884", "OS-51885", "OS-52112", 
 "OS-52956", "OS-52957", "OS-52962", "OS-52963", "OS-52964", "OS-52966", 
 "OS-52967", "OS-52968", "OS-52969", "OS-52970", "OS-54002", "OS-54004", 
 "OS-54005", "OS-54006", "OS-54007", "OS-54008", "OS-54009", "OS-54045", 
 "OS-54046", "OS-54048", "OS-54073", "OS-54074", "OS-54075", "OS-54076", 
 "OS-54077", "OS-54892", "OS-55609", "OS-55610", "OS-55611", "OS-55612", 
 "OS-55613", "OS-55614", "OS-55724", "OS-55725", "OS-55728", "OS-55729", 
 "OS-55730", "OS-55731", "OS-55732", "OS-55733", "OS-55734", "OS-55735", 
 "OS-55736", "OS-55737", "OS-58249", "OS-58250", "OS-58324", "OS-58325", 
 "OS-58326", "OS-58327", "OS-58509", "OS-58606", "OS-58607", "OS-58609", 
 "OS-58673", "OS-58674", "OS-58701", "OS-58702", "OS-58703", "OS-58704", 
 "OS-58705", "OS-58732", "OS-58735", "OS-59579", "OS-62849", "OS-62850", 
 "OS-62851", "OS-62852", "OS-62855", "OS-62985", "OS-62986", "OS-62992", 
 "OS-62994", "OS-64754", "OS-64755", "OS-64756", "OS-64759", "OS-64760", 
 "OS-64762", "OS-64764", "OS-64765", "OS-64766", "OS-64843", "OS-64844", 
 "OS-64845", "OS-64849", "OS-65398", "OS-65399", "OS-65401", "OS-65405", 
 "OS-65406", "OS-65435", "OS-65436", "OS-65437", "OS-65438", "T-10382", 
 "Unknown", "W-1381", "Y596", "Y599", "Y600", "Y602", "Y702", 
 "Y703", "Y704", "Y708", "Y711", "Y712", "Y713", "Y714", "Y716", 
 "Y717", "Y876", "Y878", "Y879", "Y882", "Y883", "Y884"), class = "factor"), 
 Type = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Above", "At", "Below"), class = "factor"), 
 RSL = c(5, 8, 17.5, 19, 27, 30, 30, 33, 35, 40, 40, 50, 53, 
 70), RSL_error = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 
 2), Age = c(8183.5, 9221.5, 10424.5, 10069, 9092, 10465.5, 
 9204.5, 10531.5, 9844.5, 10073.5, 9905, 9907.5, 11660, 10698.5
 ), age_error = c(232.5, 295.5, 519.5, 371, 323, 377.5, 336.5, 
 324.5, 318.5, 408.5, 327, 380.5, 463, 394.5), x_min_error = c(7951L, 
 8926L, 9905L, 9698L, 8769L, 10088L, 8868L, 10207L, 9526L, 
 9665L, 9578L, 9527L, 11197L, 10304L), x_max_error = c(8416L, 
 9517L, 10944L, 10440L, 9415L, 10843L, 9541L, 10856L, 10163L, 
 10482L, 10232L, 10288L, 12123L, 11093L), y_min_error = c(3, 
 6, 15.5, 17, 25, 28, 28, 31, 33, 38, 38, 48, 48, 68), y_max_error = c(7, 
 10, 19.5, 21, 29, 32, 32, 35, 37, 42, 42, 52, 58, 72)), .Names = c("SITCD", 
 "Code", "Type", "RSL", "RSL_error", "Age", "age_error", "x_min_error", 
 "x_max_error", "y_min_error", "y_max_error"), row.names = c(NA, 
 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

I wish to draw a graph using the following code:

```
g <- ggplot (df, aes(x=Age, y=RSL, shape = Type)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,15,5)) + #makes open circle/triangle
  theme(axis.line=element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid")) + # adds solid black x and y axis
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y_min_error, ymax=y_max_error,width=0,)) + # y error bar
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=x_min_error, xmax=x_max_error,height=0,)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme_bw()+ #Black outline around the graph
  xlim(0, 14000) +#Set axis limits
  ylim(0, 120) +
  #scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,14000,2000))+
  #scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,120,20))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

g
```

I was wondering why I am having difficulty setting the axes scale. I am trying to use the scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(...) code which wasn't working.  I then read elsewhere that I had to set the limits of the scales which I did with xlim/ylim but I can't use this with the scale_x_continuous code as I get the error message:

```
Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.
Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace  `xlim(0, 14000)` with `scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 15000, 1000), limits = c(0, 14000))`

Tidier code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Age, RSL, shape = Type)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = x_min_error,
                       xmax = x_max_error,
                       height = 0)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y_min_error,
                      ymax = y_max_error,
                      width = 0)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 15, 5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 120)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 15000, 1000), 
                       limits = c(0, 14000))
```

Comment: Great - thanks @PoGibas.  If I want to reverse the x axes I would usually use ... scale_x_reverse( lim=c(15000,0)) - How can I incorporate a reverse into the scale_y_continuous argument?